# Tighten up shell against forkbomb

Tags: linux, security, shell

I have a server and I have to allow remote SSH to users for some purpose. **I want to tighten up the shell against any kind of [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) on it**. How can I do this ? I'm expecting a solution based on restricting the CPU usage of a particular user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you are looking for

http://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf

You can do something like

```
@remote_user            hard    cpu             50
@remote_user            hard    nproc           50
```

Thereby limiting both the CPU usage and the number of processes the `remote_user` can create.

Comment: The link says that the <item> CPU denotes maximum CPU time in minutes. So even if i give the <value> as 1, the user can exploit it using fork bomb as fork bomb affects the system within few seconds.

Comment: @GanesshKumarRP That is why I suggested adding a limit on the number of processes too.